# Microsoft Excel: Formula bar says "Calculations!" instead of the equation used

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, excel-2013, excel-2016

I hope this is a quick and easy question for Excel pros out there.

I'm using the default "Retirement Planner" spreadsheet in MS Excel 2013. I want to make some modifications to the existing formulas, but every time I click on a cell, the formula looks something like:

=IFERROR(Calculations!G39,"")

How do I view the actual formula used to calculate the value of that cell? It seems like this syntax:

Calculations!G39

Abstracts away the underlying formula.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why not look at G39 on the "Calculations" sheet?

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a "formulas" sheet supplied with the template (or any other sheets for that matter). I think I found a way to find the formulas though -- in the "Formulas" tab, there's a "Name Manager" which seems to display the exact calculations used. It's a bit roundabout but I believe it works for me. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2):

There is a hidden Calculations sheet which you can unhide by right-clicking the Retirement Planner sheet tab and selecting Unhide from the pop-up options.

In cell G39 on the Calculations sheet is a formula `=Interest` which is reference to a Named Range.

If you go into the Name Manager on the Ribbon Formulas tab you will find that Interest contains a formula:

```
=IF(PlanYear<=PlanYears,(Calculations!F39*BeforeRetirement*InvestmentReturnPreRetirementPercentage)+(Calculations!F39*AfterRetirement*InvestmentReturnPostRetirementPercentage),NA())
```